# Changing color of group of faces

Tags: json, import, three.js, geometry

I know it's possible to change color of the faces from the object loaded/imported. But i would like to know if having a model in blender (will be exported in JSON format or OBJ) make group of faces and change the colors at runtime. This solutions is for avoiding textures, because my geometries are very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can basically export the materials out of Blender if you use a JSON. If you manipulate the MeshFaceMaterials, you manipulate the materials linked to the mesh groups.

An JSON export from Blender includes the materials for the mesh groups. You can manipulate them, in the callback function of the jsonLoader.

```
var mesh;

jsonLoader.load( url, function( geometry, materials ) {
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );

  /*
    The MeshFaceMaterial contains the exported materials from blender.
    If you manipulate one entry of the material array, every object that uses
    this material, will display the changes.
  */
  mesh.material.materials[0].color.setHex(0xff0000);

  scene.add( mesh );
});
```